# How do I display an image from an attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'd like to display an image, that I uploaded with CarrierWave, in the following code block. And ow can I define the image size?

```
  <%= simple_format(@employer.name) %>
   <% if @employer.attachment.present? %>
          <h4>Attachment</h4>
          <div class="attachment">
            <p>
              <%= link_to File.basename(@employer.attachment.url),
                @employer.attachment.url %>
             (<%= number_to_human_size(@employer.attachment.size) %>)
</p> </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `image_tag`:

```
<%= image_tag(@employer.attachment.url) %>
```

To define custom image size add version to your uploader. See [documentation on adding versions](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave#Adding_versions)

Answer (score 1):

As @Slava.K said use `image_tag`. To change image size you can use Imagemagick and MiniMagick, and define image sizes in uploader

See documentation for CarrierWave: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/